# iPhone EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to create a simple callback using blocks. 
I have a MainViewController which addSubView another DatePickerViewController.view i created a block like this

```
typedef void(^DateChangedBlock)(NSDate*);
```

And i have a method on my DatePickerViewController called

```
setOnDateChangedCallback:(DateChangedBlock)callback
```

I store the callback in a property of the DatePickerViewController. The DatePickerViewController's view is a UIDatePicker instance, ive bound an IBAction to the value changed to a method that does this.

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender {

    if (dateChangedCallback != nil)
    {
        dateChangedCallback(nil);
    }
}
```

Here is how i register the block in the MainViewController

```
DatePickerViewController *dateController = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerView" bundle:nil];

self.datePicker = dateController;
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
DateChangedBlock myBlock = ^(NSDate *newDate) {
 textView.text = @"testing";
};

[self.datePicker setOnDateChanged: myBlock];
[self.datePicker dateChanged:self]; // force trigger (this works).
```

When i force trigger the dateChanged method on the DatePickerViewController it works no problem. But when the datepicker itself triggers the method thru the IBAction i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. The error occurs in this method on the "int retVal" line.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); // THREAD 1: program received EXC_BAD_ACCCESS.**
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you change the callback method from `textView.text = @"testing";` to `NSLog(@"Testing");` does it work?

Comment: Hi Robert, yes its only if i try to access the ui elements it seems.

Comment: is `setOnDateChanged` a typo for `setOnDateChangedCallback`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should copy your block when passing it to other method (such as attribute setter in your situation). So when setting the callback block do this:

```
[self.datePicker setOnDateChanged:[[myBlock copy] autorelease]];
```

You get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS cause block's variables used when creating the block don't get retained by the block itself. So when calling the block - variables do not exist anymore.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this works when [[myBlock retain] autorelease] doesn't work, but either way this fixed my issue too so thanks!

Comment: @Cory Imdieke : You have to use copy, because blocks are created on the stack. By calling copy on the block you make a copy of it and push it to the heap so that it remains valid even after the method where it was created gets popped from the stack.

Comment: Makes sense. As I learned more about blocks I discovered that this was the case, but still good info for anyone who is just trying to wrap their head around blocks.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `setOnDateChanged:` is a method that takes a block argument. It takes complete responsibility for whether or not to copy the block. The caller never needs to copy it in this case, since it is not storing it anywhere itself.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is wrong. You don't need to copy it in your `MainViewController`. Rather, the `setOnDateChangedCallback:` method which takes a block argument is responsible for copying it if it needs to store it in an instance variable (which I see it is doing, in the variable `dateChangedCallback` that is later used by another method). If `dateChangedCallback` is a synthesized property, you can accomplish this by declaring the property as `copy` instead of `retain`.

Answer (score -3):

You can only update the UI from the UI thread. Since your block is running on another thread, you're getting the exception when updating the text of the `textView`. You can run code on the UI thread from within a block by using the main queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`).

Comment: Hi Andy, i actually tried wrapping dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); around my calls both in the block implementation and i tried doing it in the dateChanged:(id)sender IBAction that executes the block. But it still not working. Also i didnt think that it would run on another thread since normal IBAction are run on the main thread. Do blocks start they own thread?